# Yesterday was 23 hours ago

Tags: feature-request, bug

This should possibly be on Stack Exchange.

In all the review queues, the times are a bit wrong.

I am posting this close enough to 17:00 BST, so 16:00 UTC. So yesterday was 16 hours ago.

I took this screenshot at 15:52 UTC. In my history, I have 2 reviews, done today at 14:00 and 12:00. (2014-08-12). I also have 2 done at 16:00. Yesterday (2014-08-11)

[image]

Then I had another 4 (well, 6 but I cut off 2 from the screenshot) yesterday.

It thinks that 24 hours+ is yesterday, when in reality yesterday is anything since 00:00.

Pseudo code, as I have no idea what code this site uses.

```
currenttime  = 1407859825
latest midnight = 1407801600

if currenttime - timeposted >= 86400:
    display: "Yesterday"
else:
    display: (currenttime - timeposted)/86400 "hours ago"
```

It should be:

```
currenttime  = 1407859825
latestmidnight = 1407801600
timesincemidnight = currenttime - latestmidnight

if timeposted - currenttime >= timesincemidnight:
    if currenttime - timeposted >= 86400:
        display: "Yesterday"
    else:
        display: "Yesterday ("(currenttime - timeposted)/86400 "hours ago)"
else:
    display: (currenttime - timeposted)/86400 "hours ago"
```

Example for code 1. It is 16:00 (1407859200). I posted at 22:00 (1407794400) yesterday. It would think:

```
1407859200 (16:00) - 1407794400 (22:00 yesterday) = 64800
64800 >= 86400 == False
```

and display:

> 18 hours ago

Example for code 2. It is 16:00 (1407859200). I posted at 22:00 (1407794400) yesterday. Midnight was 00:00 (140780160). It would think:

```
timesincelastmidnight (tslm) = 1407859200 (16:00) - 1407801600 (00:00) = 57600

1407859200 (16:00) - 1407794400 (22:00 yesterday) = 64800
64800 >= 57600 (tslm) == True
```

and display:

> Yesterday (18 hours ago)

[@Mateo pointed out](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11757/yesterday-was-23-hours-ago#comment20274_11757) that this has already been [commented on before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/12#comment316584_12):

> "< 48*60*60s" is a rather unconventional definition for "yesterday". If it's 9am on Wednesday, would you really think of 9:01am on Monday as "yesterday". I'd have thought an algorithm for yesterday or "n days ago" should consider before/after midnight. –  Joe Feb

Comment: To be honest, I kind of like how it is now. If it's less than 24 hours, it would be nice to know the exact number.

Comment: @dan Possibly, but I find the inconsistency annoying... I will edit in your suggestion. It now displays the hours ago as well as yesterday, if it was 24 hours or less.

Comment: Time is an illusion. Lunchtime doubly so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12

Comment: @Mateo that explains it - they're essentially using the 1st example of code. In fact the first comment suggests this. Should I move this to meta.SE?